# Laravel-4: Hot to use Laravel 4 without SSH access to my server?

Tags: ssh, laravel-4

I would like to try Laravel-4 php framework and in documentation I find that is necessary to install it (not ismply copy files).

The problem is that I don't have access via SSH to my server, and until now (I'm currently using Code Igniter php framework) I simply copied my entire project files in remote folder and everything runs correctly.

Hot to use Laravel-4 without SSH access to my server?

Answer (score 1):

You're interpreting the "Installation" section of the Laravel docs a little too literally. You can build a Laravel app on your local PC or Mac and then FTP the files to your server just as you can for CodeIgniter.

You will find that there's a lot more of them though - but it's not too bad if you create a tar or zip archive and upload that, and expand it again at the other end.

However, you do lose a lot of really useful control over your sites by not having SSH access. Have you considered moving to somewhere like Digital Ocean where for $5 a month you can have a virtual server perfectly capable of running a reasonable sized Laravel application?

Comment: Hi Peter, and thank you. I'm surely considering to move to another hosting service.... :-)

Comment: I tried this but getting, internal server error, can you please help me?

Comment: Try making your storage folder and all contents writable, e.g. "chmod -R 0777 storage"

Answer (score 1):

If you want to install laravel on a server without ssh access then you should try following tools for installation that works if you have ftp access on server

[FTPloy](http://ftploy.com/)

[codeship](https://codeship.com/)

[beanstalk](http://beanstalkapp.com/)

FTPloy allows to unlimited deployments for a project

Read more [here](https://driesvints.com/blog/laravel-4-on-a-shared-host)

Note* the link tutorial is old and contain information about **laravel 4**

hope that solves your problem